# Merging files with different extensions into another file bytes

Tags: c#, file, merge

I'm trying to figure out how to attach a few files whose paths can be found at a ListBox into another file bytes. The files can have different extensions. For example one may be text document, one picture and one executable. So, when you open the main file, they all should execute in same time with the main file. I have a Server/Client project where I send the main file bytes to the server and he does his job.

```
byte[] mainFileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(MainFilePath);
int mainFileLength = mainFileBytes.Length;
byte[] mainFileLengthBuffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(mainFileLength);
Globals.GlobalBuffer = Methods.CombineBytes(mainFileLengthBuffer, mainFileBytes);
client.GetStream().Write(Globals.GlobalBuffer, 0, Globals.GlobalBuffer.Length);
```

This is how I send the main file to the server. Somehow, I have to attach those files to the main file.

Edit: Thinking of sending each of those files to the server, but the problem is that I don't know how to distinguish them.

Send code:

```
var requestBytes = new byte[26];
var requestByteCount = client.GetStream().Read(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);

if (Encoding.Unicode.GetString(requestBytes, 0, requestByteCount).Contains("ATTACHEDFILES"))
{
    if (chMFBListBox.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (string file in chMFBListBox.Items)
        {
            var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
            var fileLength = fileBytes.Length;
            var fileLengthBuffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileLength);
            Globals.GlobalBuffer = Methods.CombineBytes(fileLengthBuffer, fileBytes);
            client.GetStream().Write(Globals.GlobalBuffer, 0, Globals.GlobalBuffer.Length);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Notifying the server there aren't attached files
        Globals.GlobalBuffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("NO");
        client.GetStream().Write(Globals.GlobalBuffer, 0, Globals.GlobalBuffer.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not borrow/build upon the MIME format? Email is notorious for handling multiple files of assorted format, and this sounds like a similar use case. At the end of the day, you need some kind of contract/protocol so the sender knows its role, and likewise with the recipient.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. But I'm thinking of something like sending all files bytes to the server, but how will I be able to distinguish them